# Getting Error while creating new object of class from a Package

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I am getting this error when I am trying to create a new object

```
$provider = new ExpressCheckout;
$response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($checkoutData);
```

I am using this package https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal to integrate the PayPal ExpressCheckout in my Laravel app

This is the model from Package which I am using to create the object.

ExpressCheckout.php

```
<?php

namespace Srmklive\PayPal\Services;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface;
use Srmklive\PayPal\Traits\PayPalRequest as PayPalAPIRequest;
use Srmklive\PayPal\Traits\PayPalTransactions;
use Srmklive\PayPal\Traits\RecurringProfiles;

class ExpressCheckout
{
    // Integrate PayPal Request trait
    use PayPalAPIRequest;
    use PayPalTransactions;
    use RecurringProfiles;
    /**
     * ExpressCheckout constructor.
     *
     * @param array $config
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function __construct(array $config = [])
    {
        // Setting PayPal API Credentials
        $this->setConfig($config);

        $this->httpBodyParam = 'form_params';

        $this->options = [];
    }

    /**
     * Set ExpressCheckout API endpoints & options.
     *
     * @param array $credentials
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setExpressCheckoutOptions($credentials)
    {
        // Setting API Endpoints
        if ($this->mode === 'sandbox') {
            $this->config['api_url'] = !empty($this->config['secret']) ?
                'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp' : 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';

            $this->config['gateway_url'] = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com';
            $this->config['ipn_url'] = 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
        } else {
            $this->config['api_url'] = !empty($this->config['secret']) ?
                'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp' : 'https://api.paypal.com/nvp';

            $this->config['gateway_url'] = 'https://www.paypal.com';
            $this->config['ipn_url'] = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
        }

        // Adding params outside sandbox / live array
        $this->config['payment_action'] = $credentials['payment_action'];
        $this->config['notify_url'] = $credentials['notify_url'];
        $this->config['locale'] = $credentials['locale'];
    }

    /**
     * Set cart item details for PayPal.
     *
     * @param array $items
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    protected function setCartItems($items)
    {
        return (new Collection($items))->map(static function ($item, $num) {
            return [
                'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME'.$num  => $item['name'],
                'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'.$num   => $item['price'],
                'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC'.$num  => isset($item['desc']) ? $item['desc'] : null,
                'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY'.$num   => isset($item['qty']) ? $item['qty'] : 1,
            ];
        })->flatMap(static function ($value) {
            return $value;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Set Recurring payments details for SetExpressCheckout API call.
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @param bool  $subscription
     */
    protected function setExpressCheckoutRecurringPaymentConfig($data, $subscription = false)
    {
        $billingType = $this->billingType;

        // Overwrite billing type if $subscription flag is enabled
        if ($subscription) {
            $billingType = 'RecurringPayments';
        }

        // Send L_BILLINGTYPE0 and L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0 only if there is billing type
        if (isset($billingType)) {
            $this->post = $this->post->merge([
                'L_BILLINGTYPE0'                 => $billingType,
                'L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0' => !empty($data['subscription_desc']) ?
                    $data['subscription_desc'] : $data['invoice_description'],
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set item subtotal if available.
     *
     * @param array $data
     */
    protected function setItemSubTotal($data)
    {
        $this->subtotal = isset($data['subtotal']) ? $data['subtotal'] : $data['total'];
    }

    /**
     * Set shipping amount if available.
     *
     * @param array $data
     */
    protected function setShippingAmount($data)
    {
        if (isset($data['shipping'])) {
            $this->post = $this->post->merge([
                'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT' => $data['shipping'],
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set tax amount if available.
     *
     * @param array $data
     */
    protected function setTaxAmount($data)
    {
        if (isset($data['tax'])) {
            $this->post = $this->post->merge([
                'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT' => $data['tax'],
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set shipping discount if available.
     *
     * @param array $data
     */
    protected function setShippingDiscount($data)
    {
        if (isset($data['shipping_discount'])) {
            if ($data['shipping_discount'] > 0) {
                $data['shipping_discount'] *= -1;
            }

            $this->post = $this->post->merge([
                'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT' => $data['shipping_discount'],
                'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'         => round($data['total'] + $data['shipping_discount'], 2),
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Perform a SetExpressCheckout API call on PayPal.
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @param bool  $subscription
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array|StreamInterface
     */
    public function setExpressCheckout($data, $subscription = false)
    {
        $this->setItemSubTotal($data);

        $this->post = $this->setCartItems($data['items'])->merge([
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'       => $this->subtotal,
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'           => $data['total'],
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => $this->paymentAction,
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'  => $this->currency,
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC'          => $data['invoice_description'],
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM'        => $data['invoice_id'],
            'NOSHIPPING'                     => 1,
            'RETURNURL'                      => $data['return_url'],
            'CANCELURL'                      => $data['cancel_url'],
            'LOCALE'                         => $this->locale,
        ]);

        $this->setTaxAmount($data);

        $this->setShippingAmount($data);

        $this->setShippingDiscount($data);

        $this->setTaxAmount($data);

        $this->setExpressCheckoutRecurringPaymentConfig($data, $subscription);

        $response = $this->doPayPalRequest('SetExpressCheckout');

        return collect($response)->merge([
            'paypal_link' => !empty($response['TOKEN']) ? $this->config['gateway_url'].'/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token='.$response['TOKEN'] : null,
        ])->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Perform a GetExpressCheckoutDetails API call on PayPal.
     *
     * @param string $token
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array|StreamInterface
     */
    public function getExpressCheckoutDetails($token)
    {
        $this->setRequestData([
            'TOKEN' => $token,
        ]);

        return $this->doPayPalRequest('GetExpressCheckoutDetails');
    }

    /**
     * Perform DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call on PayPal.
     *
     * @param array  $data
     * @param string $token
     * @param string $payerId
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array|StreamInterface
     */
    public function doExpressCheckoutPayment($data, $token, $payerId)
    {
        $this->setItemSubTotal($data);

        $this->post = $this->setCartItems($data['items'])->merge([
            'TOKEN'                          => $token,
            'PAYERID'                        => $payerId,
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'       => $this->subtotal,
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'           => $data['total'],
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => !empty($this->config['payment_action']) ? $this->config['payment_action'] : 'Sale',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'  => $this->currency,
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC'          => $data['invoice_description'],
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM'        => $data['invoice_id'],
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL'     => $this->notifyUrl,
        ]);

        $this->setTaxAmount($data);

        $this->setShippingAmount($data);

        return $this->doPayPalRequest('DoExpressCheckoutPayment');
    }

    /**
     * Perform a DoAuthorization API call on PayPal.
     *
     * @param string $authorizationId Transaction ID
     * @param float  $amount          Amount to capture
     * @param array  $data            Optional request fields
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array|StreamInterface
     */
    public function doAuthorization($authorizationId, $amount, $data = [])
    {
        $this->setRequestData(
            array_merge($data, [
                'AUTHORIZATIONID' => $authorizationId,
                'AMT'             => $amount,
            ])
        );

        return $this->doPayPalRequest('DoAuthorization');
    }

    /**
     * Perform a DoCapture API call on PayPal.
     *
     * @param string $authorizationId Transaction ID
     * @param float  $amount          Amount to capture
     * @param string $complete        Indicates whether or not this is the last capture.
     * @param array  $data            Optional request fields
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array|StreamInterface
     */
    public function doCapture($authorizationId, $amount, $complete = 'Complete', $data = [])
    {
        $this->setRequestData(
            array_merge($data, [
                'AUTHORIZATIONID' => $authorizationId,
                'AMT'             => $amount,
                'COMPLETETYPE'    => $complete,
                'CURRENCYCODE'    => $this->currency,
            ])
        );

        return $this->doPayPalRequest('DoCapture');
    }

    /**
     * Perform a DoReauthorization API call on PayPal to reauthorize an existing authorization transaction.
     *
     * @param string $authorizationId
     * @param float  $amount
     * @param array  $data
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array|StreamInterface
     */
    public function doReAuthorization($authorizationId, $amount, $data = [])
    {
        $this->setRequestData(
            array_merge($data, [
                'AUTHORIZATIONID' => $authorizationId,
                'AMOUNT'          => $amount,
            ])
        );

        return $this->doPayPalRequest('DoReauthorization');
    }

    /**
     * Perform a DoVoid API call on PayPal.
     *
     * @param string $authorizationId Transaction ID
     * @param array  $data            Optional request fields
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array|StreamInterface
     */
    public function doVoid($authorizationId, $data = [])
    {
        $this->setRequestData(
            array_merge($data, [
                'AUTHORIZATIONID' => $authorizationId,
            ])
        );

        return $this->doPayPalRequest('DoVoid');
    }

    /**
     * Perform a CreateBillingAgreement API call on PayPal.
     *
     * @param string $token
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array|StreamInterface
     */
    public function createBillingAgreement($token)
    {
        $this->setRequestData([
            'TOKEN' => $token,
        ]);

        return $this->doPayPalRequest('CreateBillingAgreement');
    }

    /**
     * Perform a CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API call on PayPal.
     *
     * @param array  $data
     * @param string $token
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array|StreamInterface
     */
    public function createRecurringPaymentsProfile($data, $token)
    {
        $this->post = $this->setRequestData($data)->merge([
            'TOKEN' => $token,
        ]);

        return $this->doPayPalRequest('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile');
    }

    /**
     * Perform a GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails API call on PayPal.
     *
     * @param string $id
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array|StreamInterface
     */
    public function getRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails($id)
    {
        $this->setRequestData([
            'PROFILEID' => $id,
        ]);

        return $this->doPayPalRequest('GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails');
    }

    /**
     * Perform a UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile API call on PayPal.
     *
     * @param array  $data
     * @param string $id
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array|StreamInterface
     */
    public function updateRecurringPaymentsProfile($data, $id)
    {
        $this->post = $this->setRequestData($data)->merge([
            'PROFILEID' => $id,
        ]);

        return $this->doPayPalRequest('UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile');
    }

    /**
     * Change Recurring payment profile status on PayPal.
     *
     * @param string $id
     * @param string $status
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array|StreamInterface
     */
    protected function manageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus($id, $status)
    {
        $this->setRequestData([
            'PROFILEID' => $id,
            'ACTION'    => $status,
        ]);

        return $this->doPayPalRequest('ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus');
    }

    /**
     * Perform a ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API call on PayPal to cancel a RecurringPaymentsProfile.
     *
     * @param string $id
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array|StreamInterface
     */
    public function cancelRecurringPaymentsProfile($id)
    {
        return $this->manageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus($id, 'Cancel');
    }

    /**
     * Perform a ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API call on PayPal to suspend a RecurringPaymentsProfile.
     *
     * @param string $id
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array|StreamInterface
     */
    public function suspendRecurringPaymentsProfile($id)
    {
        return $this->manageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus($id, 'Suspend');
    }

    /**
     * Perform a ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API call on PayPal to reactivate a RecurringPaymentsProfile.
     *
     * @param string $id
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array|StreamInterface
     */
    public function reactivateRecurringPaymentsProfile($id)
    {
        return $this->manageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus($id, 'Reactivate');
    }
}
```

PayPalRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace Srmklive\PayPal\Traits;

use Exception;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as HttpClient;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface;
use RuntimeException;
use Srmklive\PayPal\Services\AdaptivePayments;
use Srmklive\PayPal\Services\ExpressCheckout;

trait PayPalRequest
{
    use PayPalHttpClient;

    /**
     * Http Client class object.
     *
     * @var HttpClient
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * Http Client configuration.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $httpClientConfig;

    /**
     * PayPal API Certificate data for authentication.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $certificate;

    /**
     * PayPal API mode to be used.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $mode;

    /**
     * Request data to be sent to PayPal.
     *
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $post;

    /**
     * PayPal API configuration.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * Item subtotal.
     *
     * @var float
     */
    private $subtotal;

    /**
     * Default currency for PayPal.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $currency;

    /**
     * Default billing type for PayPal reference transactions.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $billingType;

    /**
     * Additional options for PayPal API request.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $options;

    /**
     * Default payment action for PayPal.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $paymentAction;

    /**
     * Default locale for PayPal.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $locale;

    /**
     * PayPal API Endpoint.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $apiUrl;

    /**
     * IPN notification url for PayPal.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $notifyUrl;

    /**
     * Http Client request body parameter name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $httpBodyParam;

    /**
     * Validate SSL details when creating HTTP client.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    private $validateSSL;

    /**
     * Set PayPal API Credentials.
     *
     * @param array $credentials
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setApiCredentials($credentials)
    {
        // Setting Default PayPal Mode If not set
        $this->setApiEnvironment($credentials);

        // Set API configuration for the PayPal provider
        $this->setApiProviderConfiguration($credentials);

        // Set default currency.
        $this->setCurrency($credentials['currency']);

        // Set default billing type
        $this->setBillingType($credentials['billing_type']);

        // Set Http Client configuration.
        $this->setHttpClientConfiguration();
    }

    /**
     * Set other/override PayPal API parameters.
     *
     * @param array $options
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addOptions(array $options)
    {
        $this->options = $options;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Function to set currency.
     *
     * @param string $currency
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCurrency($currency = 'USD')
    {
        $allowedCurrencies = ['AUD', 'BRL', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'INR', 'JPY', 'MYR', 'MXN', 'NOK', 'NZD', 'PHP', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'TWD', 'THB', 'USD', 'RUB'];

        // Check if provided currency is valid.
        if (!in_array($currency, $allowedCurrencies, true)) {
            throw new Exception('Currency is not supported by PayPal.');
        }

        $this->currency = $currency;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Function to set billing type.
     *
     * @param string $billingType
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBillingType($billingType = 'MerchantInitiatedBilling')
    {
        $allowedBillingTypes = ['MerchantInitiatedBilling', 'MerchantInitiatedBillingSingleAgreement', 'RecurringPayments'];

        if ($billingType !== null && !in_array($billingType, $allowedBillingTypes, true)) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Billing type is not supported by PayPal.');
        }

        $this->billingType = $billingType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve PayPal IPN Response.
     *
     * @param array $post
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function verifyIPN($post)
    {
        $this->setRequestData($post);

        $this->apiUrl = $this->config['ipn_url'];

        return $this->doPayPalRequest('verifyipn');
    }

    /**
     * Setup request data to be sent to PayPal.
     *
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    protected function setRequestData(array $data = [])
    {
        if (($this->post instanceof Collection) && (!$this->post->isEmpty())) {
            unset($this->post);
        }

        $this->post = new Collection($data);

        return $this->post;
    }

    /**
     * Function To Set PayPal API Configuration.
     *
     * @param array $config
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private function setConfig(array $config = [])
    {
        // Set Api Credentials
        if (function_exists('config')) {
            $this->setApiCredentials(
                config('paypal')
            );
        } elseif (!empty($config)) {
            $this->setApiCredentials($config);
        }

        $this->setRequestData();
    }

    /**
     * Set default values for configuration.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function setDefaultValues()
    {
        // Set default payment action.
        if (empty($this->paymentAction)) {
            $this->paymentAction = 'Sale';
        }

        // Set default locale.
        if (empty($this->locale)) {
            $this->locale = 'en_US';
        }

        // Set default value for SSL validation.
        if (empty($this->validateSSL)) {
            $this->validateSSL = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set API environment to be used by PayPal.
     *
     * @param array $credentials
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function setApiEnvironment($credentials)
    {
        if (empty($credentials['mode']) || !in_array($credentials['mode'], ['sandbox', 'live'])) {
            $this->mode = 'live';
        } else {
            $this->mode = $credentials['mode'];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set configuration details for the provider.
     *
     * @param array $credentials
     *
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function setApiProviderConfiguration($credentials)
    {
        // Setting PayPal API Credentials
        collect($credentials[$this->mode])->map(function ($value, $key) {
            $this->config[$key] = $value;
        });

        // Setup PayPal API Signature value to use.
        $this->config['signature'] = empty($this->config['certificate']) ?
        $this->config['secret'] : $this->config['certificate'];

        $this->paymentAction = $credentials['payment_action'];

        $this->locale = $credentials['locale'];

        $this->certificate = $this->config['certificate'];

        $this->validateSSL = $credentials['validate_ssl'];

        $this->setApiProvider($credentials);
    }

    /**
     * Determines which API provider should be used.
     *
     * @param array $credentials
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private function setApiProvider($credentials)
    {
        if ($this instanceof AdaptivePayments) {
            return $this->setAdaptivePaymentsOptions();
        }

        if ($this instanceof ExpressCheckout) {
            return $this->setExpressCheckoutOptions($credentials);
        }

        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid api credentials provided for PayPal!. Please provide the right api credentials.');
    }

    /**
     * Create request payload to be sent to PayPal.
     *
     * @param string $method
     */
    private function createRequestPayload($method)
    {
        $config = array_merge([
            'USER'      => $this->config['username'],
            'PWD'       => $this->config['password'],
            'SIGNATURE' => $this->config['signature'],
            'VERSION'   => 123,
            'METHOD'    => $method,
        ], $this->options);

        $this->post = $this->post->merge($config);
        if ($method === 'verifyipn') {
            $this->post->forget('METHOD');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parse PayPal NVP Response.
     *
     * @param string                $method
     * @param array|StreamInterface $response
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function retrieveData($method, $response)
    {
        if ($method === 'verifyipn') {
            return $response;
        }

        parse_str($response, $output);

        return $output;
    }
}
```

**Error Message**

> ErrorException Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Comment: Where is `$this->config` defined?

Comment: It is defined in PaypalRequest.php
let me update the code with that file

Comment: @jrswgtr I have updated the code. but here what setConfig looks like.

private function setConfig(array $config = [])
    {
        // Set Api Credentials
        if (function_exists('config')) {
            $this->setApiCredentials(
                config('paypal')
            );
        } elseif (!empty($config)) {
            $this->setApiCredentials($config);
        }

        $this->setRequestData();
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running these commands

```
composer update 

php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan view:clear
```